# how to find how much time explicit wait took for condition to be true in selenium web driver java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
```

How long did the driver wait for this condition to be true?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
long durationMs = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
```